# Removing a class after a CSS animation has finished - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I have a preloader on my site that has a screen that comes down and then when the page is loaded, the screen goes back up.

This is working on some of my sites pages but on the pages where it loads really quick, the screen comes down but doesn't seem to come back up...

Does anyone know why this might be and how to fix it?

Any help will be appreciated. My code is below.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('.prepage').addClass("animation");
  $('.prepage').one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
              function(event) {
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('.prepage').removeClass("animation");
        $('.prepage').addClass("done");
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.prepage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

.animation {
    top: 0;
}

.done {
    top: -100% !important;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

.loader-inside {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.existing {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.headtype {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prepage"><div class="loader-inside"><p class="existing">LOADING...</p></div></div>
```

Comment: I think the logic is flawed. After the transition ends, you are setting a listener for the window to finish loading. Why? Just remove your class after the animation ends. What's the `$(window).on('load')` doing here? Besides, you already have a `document.ready` wrapping everything. Currently, you are finishing the transition, then setting a listener for the window to load, then removing the classes. This is why it doesn't work `where it loads really quick`, because the `window.onload` event has already happened when the transition ends.

Comment: I see this now. Thank you. I have tried it a different way and it now seems to be working. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for these guys. I tried the delay but it didn't work as it didn't cover the content on the page underneath all the time.

I managed to fix it like this in the end...

It doesn't work on the example on here but on the live site, it does!

Thanks for all the help and advice :)

```js
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    $('.prepage').css('top', '0');
});

$(window).bind('load', function(){
    $('.prepage').css('top', '-100vh');
});
```

```css
.prepage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: $pink;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999999;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prepage"><div class="loader-inside"><p class="existing">HOLD TIGHT...</p></span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can queue the class removal operation with [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) this will add a delay when it's loaded, fro example here will wait for 1 second before goes back up

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('.prepage').addClass("animation");
  $('.prepage').one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
                function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).queue(function() {  // Wait for 1 second.
          $(this).removeClass("animation").dequeue();
         $(this).addClass("done");
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.prepage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

.animation {
    top: 0;
}

.done {
    top: -100% !important;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

.loader-inside {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.existing {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.headtype {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prepage"><div class="loader-inside"><p class="existing">LOADING...</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I ended up shortening it and built it a bit differently but the `.queue` you used here helped me a lot when trying to get the new version working so thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Use [SetTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

In this example, the code will wait for 1sec (1000ms)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('.prepage').addClass("animation");
  $('.prepage').one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
              function(event) {
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('.prepage').removeClass("animation");
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('.prepage').addClass("done");
        }, 1000)
      });
  });
});
```